# Cost minimization and then log differentiation

Tags: microeconomics, cost-functions

I have trouble deriving the third equation from the second one. The model is in: https://www.nber.org/papers/w30240

The firm's cost minimization problem is as follows:

\begin{equation}
\min _{L_i, \boldsymbol{X}_i} \sum_{j=1}^N p_j x_{i j}+w_i L_i \quad \text { subject to } A_i G\left(L_i, \boldsymbol{X}_i\right) \geq \bar{y}_i
\end{equation}

In equilibrium, sectoral good prices equal sectoral marginal costs
\begin{equation}
p_i=M C_i\left(A_i, w_i, \boldsymbol{p}\right)
\end{equation}

Then, as the author says by log differentiation, they can get

$$
d \log p_i=\alpha_i d \log w_i+\sum_{j=1}^N \Omega_{i j} d \log p_j-d \log A_i
$$
where
$$
\Omega_{i j}=\frac{p_j x_{i j}}{p_i y_i} \quad \text { and } \alpha_i=\frac{w_i L_i}{p_i y_i}
$$

Actually, in Baqaee and Farhi (2022) AER (which is the theoretical framework of this paper), they say it can be derived by Shephard's lemma. I don't understand this method, either.

Can anyone help me understand this step? Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for setting out the equations clearly using Latex.  As the paper you link to runs to 66 pages and contains many equations, it would be helpful if you could indicate the relevant page number(s) rather than leaving it to the reader to search through the paper.

Comment: Sorry for that. It is at the start of Appendix A.1.1